# Are there URL-level SQL injection protections built into PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I'm working with AJAX and trying to send a multi-command SQL query and I'm being stopped, as near as I can tell, at a very low level.

I have a simple PHP file:

```
<?
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
print("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?><root></root>");
?>
```

With this setup, as near as I can tell, sending a request which contains:

- a semicolon, followed by
- the word INSERT, followed by
- two or more characters

...will result in a 403 Forbidden response. *ANY* deviation from that goes through without any trouble. So this:

```
http://my.server.com/myfile.php?x=%3BINSERTXX
```

...returns a 403 error. But all of these:

```
http://my.server.com/myfile.php?x=%3CINSERTXX
http://my.server.com/myfile.php?x=%3BINSERTX
http://my.server.com/myfile.php?x=%3BINSERQXX
```

...go through just fine.

This is such a specific thing (and one that's taken me all morning to narrow down) that it seems obviously oriented toward preventing SQL injection. That's fine, I appreciate the protection from [Bobby Tables' mom](https://xkcd.com/327/).* But supposing I'm taking appropriate precautions in my code, how can I send a multi-part SQL command via AJAX? Is there some PHP setting I need to change on the server to allow this, or some other way I can send multiple INSERT commands in a single AJAX transaction?

Thanks!

EDIT: Here's what I'm talking about. I've placed the exact PHP file above on my server. Try the following URLs:

- http://tobyrush.com/sql.php?x=%3BINSERTXX
- http://tobyrush.com/sql.php?x=%3CINSERTXX
- http://tobyrush.com/sql.php?x=%3BINSERTX
- http://tobyrush.com/sql.php?x=%3BINSERQXX

*It's worth mentioning, however, that replacing "INSERT" with "DROP" *doesn't* return a 403...

Comment: i don't really understand your question... how can a simple file with just a XML header return a 403 error ? but to answer to the question in your title, PHP does not secure anything for you, it has tools which can be used to secure your database but you have to tell php to use them

Comment: "how can a simple file with just a XML header return a 403 error ?" My thoughts exactly. I've edited my question with some examples so you can see what I'm talking about.

Comment: there must be something in your apache configuration which throws this error : i just tested this file with the built-in php server on my computer and everything went fine

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for helping me track it down!